# Battery reminder POSIX script having issues with DBUS

Tags: cron, posix, dbus, notify-send

### I wrote a POSIX shell script to remind me about my battery life using notify-send and a cronjob, but I'm having problems with DBUS stuff

This is what the script looks like

`#!/bin/sh`

`` percent=`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage: ``

`notify-send "battery life" "$percent"`

It works as intended, and pops up with this notification when called.

I wrote the script because my window manager, i3 lacks a notification system for battery status, so I found myself running out of battery on my laptop even though I was right next to an outlet at home.

Of course; having a script like this is pointlesss unless it's automated to pop up by itself, so after some fiddling, I set up a Cron-job that runs the script every 10 minutes.

This is what the cron-tab looks like:
`*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 ; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=a; batterystatus.sh`

It works, except that without the little snippet about the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS stuff, for some reason `notify-status` doesn't work.

So, everything was cool until I rebooted and found that this value used in the cron-tab: `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-FOSTebXqX5,guid=a7ad198d91d224b8c056efc6615a3610` changes upon boot.
That means that I would have to change the cron-job everytime I boot up my computer so that the script would work.
 Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried getting the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/346580/100386)? That one is for Gnome, not i3, but it should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `crontab`, it might be better to use `systemd`. You can have a systemd user service and timer so that D-Bus has access to the session D-Bus information for session notifications.

I've tested this out using the Python dbus library [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) as an example bus I'm sure you could use your shell script also.

Python script for getting battery power and posting notifications:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pydbus

sys_bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
ses_bus = pydbus.SessionBus()

power = sys_bus.get('.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0')
notifications = ses_bus.get('.Notifications')

print(power.Percentage)

notifications.Notify('test', 0, 'dialog-information', "Battery Notification!",
                     f"Percentage: {power.Percentage}%", [], {}, 5000)
```

Created a user service in `/etc/systemd/user/battery.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check for battery percentage

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.Notifications
ExecStart=/home/thinkabit1/stack_overflow/battery_monitor.py
```

You can test this works with:

```
$ systemctl --user start battery.service
```

To see the status of the service do:

```
$ systemctl --user status battery.service
```

To have a timer run this every 10 minutes create `/etc/systemd/user/battery.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run battery monitor every 10 minutes

[Timer]
OnBootSec=10min
OnUnitActiveSec=10min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

This can be started with:

```
$ systemctl --user start battery.timer
```

To see the status:

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers
```

To have it start automatically after reboot use:

```
systemctl --user enable battery.timer
```